# SQL: JOIN syntax error

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I am attempting to eliminate unwanted duplicate query results. The gist is that the field [CUSIP] exists in all tables in question, however, the field [4DTYR] exists in all tables except [IDX_FS].

I had previously only joined the tables via the [CUSIP] field, and that resulted in the query produced unwanted duplicate results (some sort of a permutation of [4DTYR] from all the tables that contained that field).

Then, I made the modification below. However, now I'm receiving a JOIN syntax error. Can anyone kindly help? Thanks!

```
FROM 

(((IDX_FS LEFT JOIN DATA_BS 
  ON IDX_FS.CUSIP = DATA_BS.CUSIP) 

LEFT JOIN DATA_Footnotes 
  ON IDX_FS.CUSIP = DATA_Footnotes.CUSIP) 

LEFT JOIN DATA_IS 
  ON IDX_FS.CUSIP = DATA_IS.CUSIP) 

LEFT JOIN DATA_SP 
  ON IDX_FS.CUSIP = DATA_SP.CUSIP 

AND (((DATA_BS LEFT JOIN DATA_IS 
  ON DATA_BS.CUSIP = DATA_IS.CUSIP 
     AND DATA_BS.4DTYR = DATA_IS.4DTYR) 

LEFT JOIN DATA_SP 
  ON DATA_BS.CUSIP = DATA_SP.CUSIP 
     AND DATA_BS.4DTYR = DATA_SP.4DTYR) 

LEFT JOIN DATA_Footnotes.4DTYR 
  ON DATA_BS.CUSIP = DATA_Footnotes.CUSIP 
     AND DATA_BS.4DTYR = DATA_Footnotes.4DTYR
```

Comment: Please format your code?

Comment: Hi, just tried reformatted to the best of my abilities. I'm really new to this!

Comment: Why are you reposting your question again and again?

Comment: You have already posted [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19470044/806549) and subsequently [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472564/sql-syntax-error-join). Please see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110666/213634) for further info.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have one `(` too many:

```
FROM 
     (
      (
       (IDX_FS LEFT JOIN DATA_BS ON IDX_FS.CUSIP = DATA_BS.CUSIP) 
       LEFT JOIN DATA_Footnotes ON IDX_FS.CUSIP = DATA_Footnotes.CUSIP
      ) 
      LEFT JOIN DATA_IS ON IDX_FS.CUSIP = DATA_IS.CUSIP
     ) 
     LEFT JOIN DATA_SP ON IDX_FS.CUSIP = DATA_SP.CUSIP AND 
     ( -- This is unmatched
      (
       (DATA_BS LEFT JOIN DATA_IS ON DATA_BS.CUSIP = DATA_IS.CUSIP AND DATA_BS.4DTYR = DATA_IS.4DTYR)     
       LEFT JOIN DATA_SP ON DATA_BS.CUSIP = DATA_SP.CUSIP AND DATA_BS.4DTYR = DATA_SP.4DTYR
      ) 
      LEFT JOIN DATA_Footnotes.4DTYR ON DATA_BS.CUSIP = DATA_Footnotes.CUSIP AND DATA_BS.4DTYR = DATA_Footnotes.4DTYR
     -- A ) here perhaps?
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried your edit and now i'm getting a missing operator error?

Comment: There is something more wrong before the unmatched parenthesis, I guess. Should the `AND`really be there?

Comment: I'm such a noob that I can't tell! I'm trying it without the AND now.

Answer (score 0):

In the FROM phase we specify table or tables that need to be queried, and if table operators
are specified, this phase processes those operators from left to right. Join (Left / Right) are table operators and each table operator operates on one or two input tables and returns an output table. The result of a table operator is used as the left input to the next table operator—if one exists—and as the input to the next logical query processing phase otherwise.
In your query i find two issues:

1. DO you want entire 'AND' condition(Line 15) to be added as a filter condition in ON clause when left joining with DATA_SP?
2. In Last line you are trying to specify a left join on field [4DTYR] of DATA_Footnotes table which is not right as the Left join operator expects a table to be supplied.

I think a pseudo like below might help:

```
select IDX_FS.CUSIP , DATA_BS.[4DTYR] 
FROM 
  IDX_FS
  LEFT JOIN DATA_BS 
  ON IDX_FS.CUSIP = DATA_BS.CUSIP
  LEFT JOIN DATA_Footnotes 
  ON IDX_FS.CUSIP = DATA_Footnotes.CUSIP AND DATA_BS.CUSIP = DATA_Footnotes.CUSIP  AND DATA_BS.[4DTYR] = DATA_Footnotes.[4DTYR]
  LEFT JOIN DATA_IS 
  ON IDX_FS.CUSIP = DATA_IS.CUSIP AND DATA_BS.CUSIP = DATA_IS.CUSIP AND DATA_BS.[4DTYR] = DATA_IS.[4DTYR]
  LEFT JOIN DATA_SP 
  ON IDX_FS.CUSIP = DATA_SP.CUSIP AND DATA_BS.CUSIP = DATA_SP.CUSIP AND DATA_BS.[4DTYR] = DATA_SP.[4DTYR]
  -- LEFT JOIN DATA_Footnotes.[4DTYR] no need.
```

Hope this helps!!!