# SQL Syntax Error - JOIN

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, syntax

I am attempting to eliminate unwanted duplicate query results. The gist is that the field [CUSIP] exists in all tables in question, however, the field [4DTYR] exists in all tables except [IDX_FS].

I had previously only joined the tables via the [CUSIP] field, and that resulted in the query produced unwanted duplicate results (some sort of a permutation of [4DTYR] from all the tables that contained that field).

Then, I made the modification below. However, now I'm receiving a JOIN syntax error. Can anyone kindly help? I've reposted just in case this Q got a little bit stale. Thanks!

```
FROM 

(((IDX_FS LEFT JOIN DATA_BS 
  ON IDX_FS.CUSIP = DATA_BS.CUSIP) 

LEFT JOIN DATA_Footnotes 
  ON IDX_FS.CUSIP = DATA_Footnotes.CUSIP) 

LEFT JOIN DATA_IS 
  ON IDX_FS.CUSIP = DATA_IS.CUSIP) 

LEFT JOIN DATA_SP 
  ON IDX_FS.CUSIP = DATA_SP.CUSIP 

AND (((DATA_BS LEFT JOIN DATA_IS 
  ON DATA_BS.CUSIP = DATA_IS.CUSIP 
     AND DATA_BS.4DTYR = DATA_IS.4DTYR) 

LEFT JOIN DATA_SP 
  ON DATA_BS.CUSIP = DATA_SP.CUSIP 
     AND DATA_BS.4DTYR = DATA_SP.4DTYR) 

LEFT JOIN DATA_Footnotes.4DTYR 
  ON DATA_BS.CUSIP = DATA_Footnotes.CUSIP 
     AND DATA_BS.4DTYR = DATA_Footnotes.4DTYR
```

Comment: I get "missing operator" syntax error....

Comment: [Don't repost questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110666/213634) just because you don't get an answer immediately. You've asked the same [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19470044/806549) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19472263/806549).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your error is here

```
LEFT JOIN DATA_Footnotes.4DTYR -- this is not a valid table name
  ON DATA_BS.CUSIP = DATA_Footnotes.CUSIP 
   AND DATA_BS.4DTYR = DATA_Footnotes.4DTYR
```

removing the `.4DTYR` should fix your error

```
LEFT JOIN DATA_Footnotes
  ON DATA_BS.CUSIP = DATA_Footnotes.CUSIP 
   AND DATA_BS.4DTYR = DATA_Footnotes.4DTYR
```

Comment: That's a legit error. However, I made the change and I'm still getting a missing operator error. Should I be using UNION to connect two SELECT statements instead?